# postgreSQL query error with join with subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is in postgreSQL, here is the table:

```
create type platform as enum ('desktop', 'mobile');
create table spending (
user_id int,
spend_date date,
platform platform,
amount int
);

alter table spending
add primary key (user_id, spend_date, platform);

insert into spending values
(1, '2019-07-01', 'mobile', 100), 
(1, '2019-07-01', 'desktop', 100), 
(2, '2019-07-01', 'mobile', 100), 
(2, '2019-07-02', 'mobile', 100), 
(3, '2019-07-01', 'desktop', 100), 
(3, '2019-07-02', 'desktop', 100);
```

trying to get all unique date and cross join with a subquery which generates a simple table with 'desktop', 'mobile', and 'both'. here is the query:

```
select distinct s.spend_date, 
       t.platform 
from spending s join (select 'desktop' platform union 
                      select 'mobile' platform union 
                      select 'both' platform) t;
```

error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 5:        select 'both' platform) t;
```

spent some time on this one but still can't figure out the error. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a table alias and a `join` condition.  Also, `values()` is simpler.  Perhaps:

```
select s.spend_date, v.platform 
from spending s cross join
     (values ('desktop'), ('mobile'), ('both')
     ) v(platform);
```

I replaced the `join` with `cross join` so no `on` clause is needed.